# Determining whether a set of points is contained on an ellipse

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

My problem is quite broad, but I wanted to know if there exists any results on this: if $\mathcal{P}$ is a set of $n$ points, then what are necessary and sufficient conditions for these $n$ points being contained on an ellipse? Does there exists any theorems / lemmas on this?

Comment: I think this question has nothing to do with graph theory.

Comment: Will the Pascal's theorem be useful?

Comment: You need to check if the sum of distances from the foci is, for every point, less than the major axis. Necessary and sufficient condition.

Answer (score 2):

Let $n$ be the number of points.

If $n\le 4$ and the points are not collinear, then you can always find an ellipse on which the points lie.

If $n \ge 5$, then take any $5$ of the points, and construct the conic on which these points lie.  The conic equation can be found from the following determinant

$\begin{vmatrix} x^2 &&  xy &&y^2 && x && y && 1 \\
x_1^2 &&  x_1y_1 &&y_1^2 && x_1 && y_1 && 1\\
x_2^2 &&  x_2y_2 &&y_2^2 && x_2 && y_2 && 1\\
x_3^2 &&  x_3y_3 &&y_3^2 && x_3 && y_3 && 1\\
x_4^2 &&  x_4y_4 && y_4^2 &&x_4 && y_4 && 1\\
x_5^2 &&  x_5y_5 &&y_5^2 && x_5 && y_5 && 1 \end{vmatrix} = 0 $

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_points_determine_a_conic) for details.

If this conic is an ellipse, then you can check the other points by direct substitution in the ellipse that you found.

Comment: Is there a way to determine when a conic is an ellipse?

Comment: Yes.  Suppose the equation of the conic that you obtained from mentioned determinant is $A x^2 + B xy + C y^2 + D x + E y + F = 0$, then this will represent an ellipse if $ A C - (B^2/4) \gt 0$